# How to check whether a v-checkbox is selected in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods, v-for

I have a checkbox with the following events and props:

```
   <v-checkbox
          v-for="planets in allPlanets" :key="`planets_${planets.id}`"
          :label="planets.name"
          :value="planets.id"
          v-model="selectedPlanets"
   />
```

Given that all of the checkboxes are brought in using a v-for, how can I check whether a checkbox is selected using a method or mounted function in Vue JS?

For example:

```
    methods: {
       checkSelected() {  
           ????
       },
```

Comment: Assuming `selectedPlanets` an array, are you just trying to check which planet IDs it contains? What do you want to do with those values?

Answer (score 0):

Add a planets.selected key.

```
 allPlanets: [
      { name: 'Planet name', value: 'Planet value' , selected : false },
       ...,
       ...
      ],
    }
```

And in your template:

```
  <v-checkbox
          v-for="planets in allPlanets" :key="`planets_${planets.id}`"
          :label="planets.name"
          :value="planets.id"
          v-model="planets.selected"
   />
```

Similar to:

[Display multiple checkbox in table format using <v-for> and <v-checkbox> in Vuetify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052395/display-multiple-checkbox-in-table-format-using-v-for-and-v-checkbox-in-vuet/51053394)

Answer (score 0):

you have to make such a structure, so you know for each id, whether it is checked or not

```js
new Vue({
    data: () => ({
        allPlanets: [
            {
                id: 32,
                name: "planent",
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: 365,
                name: "planet 2",
                selected: false
            }
        ],
    }),
    methods: {
        checkSelectedByIndex(index) {
            return this.allPlanets[index].selected
        },
        checkSelectedById(id) {
            return this.allPlanets.find(p => p.id === id)?.selected ?? false
        }
    }
});
```

and in the  you have to set the    **v-model="planets.selected"**

Answer (score 0):

Given your layout the simplest methods is:

```
methods: {
   checkSelected(id) {
       return this.selectedPlanets.includes(id)
   },
}
```